# Arduino . Overriding light sensor (LDR) through bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, arduino, sensors, light

This is my circuit.
[image]
I have a photoresistor that lights up when dark. Also i have connected a working bluetooth module.

```
const int ledPin = 13;
const int ldrPin = A0;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(ldrPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
    int ldrStatus = analogRead(ldrPin);

    if(ldrStatus <= 300) {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
        Serial.println("LDR is DARK, LED is ON");
    }
    else {
        digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
        Serial.println("---------------");
    }
}
```

My goal is for the photoresistor to work automatically (as it already does) + using bluetooth application to turn the LED on/off when I decide despite the resistor (overriding its function), so when it is dark and the light is on, but you want to turn it off, just use the "OFF" button from the application. I am using "Arduino Bluetooth" app from Circuit Magic which has 2 buttons on/off for the LED. The problem what code I should write. All help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the characters received in the serial port.

You can use the base code [HERE](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SerialEvent) and adapt it to your needs:

```
void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    // get the new byte:
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
    // add it to the inputString:
    inputString += inChar;
    // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag so the main loop can
    // do something about it:
    if (inChar == '\n') {
      stringComplete = true;

      // Here you process the received character and turn the led ON or OFF accordingly

      if (strcmp(inputString, "OFF"))
         digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
      else if (strcmp(inputString, "ON"))
         digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
    }
  }
}
```

You will need to initialize some variables in your code to make it work.

Also in your code you should put some anti-bouncing protection, otherwise if the LDR value changes quickly your LED will blink instantly. Usually you want to have some inertia to prevent this.